# How to reference database properties using Digital Ocean bindable variables?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, digital-ocean

Using DigitalOcean's managed Postgres database cluster and App Platform, I want to connect my NodeJS app to my Postgres database.

At the moment, I'm getting the time out error below. As part of debugging the misconfiguration, I want to verify that I'm using the bindable app environment variables correctly.

Here are some basic details. Using this information, can you help me to understand how to construct the bindable variable?

- Database Cluster Name: `demo`
- Database Pool Name: `Demo`
- Example database Name: `defaultdb`
- App Platform > App Name: `demo1`

I've tried an assortment of combinations as shown below. When I run the `echo $MY_VAR` command, none of these values are interpolated. I see the bindable variable syntax.

```bash
# Test using database cluster name only.
apps@client:~$ echo $TEST1
${demo.HOSTNAME}

# Test using _self, or the current context. I believe this is the app context.
apps@client:~$ echo $TEST2
${_self.HOSTNAME}

# Test using syntax of <db_cluster_name>.<db_pool_name>.<env_var>
apps@client:~$ echo $TEST3
${demo.Demo.HOSTNAME}

# Test using syntax of <app_name>.<db_pool_name>.<env_var>
apps@client:~$ echo $TEST4
${demo1.Demo.HOSTNAME}
```

Most of these are a bit ridiculous, and at this point, I'm just experimenting with various combinations. **Can you please help me to understand the syntax that would output the database hostname when I run `echo $DB_HOSTNAME` from the Digital Ocean app console?** Thank you.

##### Why am I trying to confirm the bindable variable syntax?

I'd like to use the [app environment variables for databases](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#databases). Because of the connection refused, I believe the issue might be related to the CA certificate not being available as part of the Postgres connection details. Since my syntax isn't resolving, the CA cert isn't available when connecting to Postgres in my code.

The bindable variables should be populated in Node's environment variables and available through `process.env`.

```
# Sample postgres configuration
const postgresConfig = {
   user: process.env.PG_USER,
   password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
   host: process.env.PG_HOST,
   database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
   port: process.env.PG_PORT,
   ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      ca: process.env.PG_CA_CERT,
   },
};
```

##### Error message

When attempting to run a Postgres query, I get this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.x.y.z:25061
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
  errno: -110,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.x.y.x',
  port: 25061
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I didn't realize that I needed to attach the database to the app. Feeling kind of dumb right now. Once, I attached it, I now see a helpful drop down menu of options in the DO console.

Answer (score 0):

I see how it works now. When you are managing your App Platform application, under the **Create** menu button is the option to "Create/Attach Database".

I didn't look here because I didn't think I would need to use the "Create" button to attach an existing database. It would be more intuitive to find this feature under the "Actions" menu. I fell victim to some peculiar UI design decisions.

Once the database is attached, all is well in the world.

[image]